# Magento Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize()

Tags: magento

I have three products assigned to a category below the default category. Manage Categories shows the Category is active and the Category Products tab shows the three products correctly. The category is shown as ID:4

In CMS > Pages > Home Page > Content I have:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

After clearing cache and reindexing (many times now) the home page gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on a non-object in /home8/mauipine/public_html/magento/app/design/frontend/default/pineapple/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar_top.phtml on line 34

I have tried many solutions found here and on the Magento site but have been unable to resolve the error. If I use non-existent category_id, e.g. 3 I do not get an error but simply get "There are no products matching the selection."

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be difficult for someone to give you a concrete answer on this.  As Per your error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on a non-object in /home8/mauipine/public_html/magento/app/design/frontend/default/pineapple/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar_top.phtml on line 34

The `toolbar_top.phtml` file is not (to my knowledge) part of any standard Magento installation.  Your custom `pineapple` theme added this file, and somehow incorporated it into your Magento system's layout.  Unfortunately, it appears to be incompatible with the `catalog/product_list` block call you're making.   Somewhere in that file you'll see a call to `getSize`, something like this (the variable probably won't be named `$object`)

```
$object->getSize();
```

The brute force fix would be to add conditional code around that statement otherwise account for the face `$object` might not be instantiated.

```
if(is_object($object))
{
    $object->getSize();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for looking. Actually, the toolbar_top.phtml file was copied from the mobileshoppe theme and is unchanged. Perhaps I should mention that this error occurred after using the cart2carte conversion and their only proposal was to reindex which of course I have done. Funny thing is that a test conversion worked fine but the full conversion did not. Before full conversion the catalog_id was 3  but now is 4 but setting  that catalog_id as described gives the rror.

Comment: I have solved the problem. I was working on it for a friend and did not realize that the site when working had previously used the default theme not the pineapple theme. Sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score 1):

Great thanks! I had the same problem with 7 In One Catalog By etatvasoft extension and mobileshoppe theme. It is enough to change first condition in toolbar_top and toolbar_bottom template this way:

`<?php if(is_object($this->getCollection()) and $this->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>`